# Highlight/extract rows that consist of a specific value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im not sure if this can be done in excel but here goes.

Im looking for a way to either extract/highlight a list of OrderID & with its related products only if the OrderID has Product "A" while ignoring the other orderID's that does not have A.

I have tried using IF statements to detect Product "A" but it could not check the subsequent OrderID rows. I also thought of using Concatenate/Textjoin but couldn't make it work.

***Screenshot of sample data:***

[image]

Result im trying to achieve

[image: Screenshot of result data]

It should only highlights/extract the OrderID's 6613,7557 and 3396 (along with the other products values) as these OrderID's has product "A". While it ignore other OrderIDs that does not have Product "A" (eg. 4519,7601,2113,9880)

Edited: attached 2 pictures to differentiate sample and results

Comment: What version of Excel have you got? If O365, you could use new DA-functions like `FILTER`. If not, another easy approach is to pivot your data.

Comment: From where these `4519,7601,2113,9880` are coming as not in your product list?

Comment: @Harun24HR Sorry, I've mixed up the sample list (on left side) and results (right side). Its in Column B. 4519 (rows 8 & 9), 7601 (rows 10-12), 2113 (row 15) & 9880 (row 16). These rows does not have Product A. FYI: Im using O365 :)

Comment: Then what are you trying to achieve? These are already in your desired result list. These ID do you want to highlight as well. Can you please put a separate picture with you exact output.

Comment: Attached a separate picture on the results im looking for. Sorry about the confusion earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have O365:

```
F2: =FILTER($B$2:$C$17,COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$17,$B$2:$B$17,$C$2:$C$17,"A"))
```

If you have an earlier version of Excel:

```
=INDEX(B2:C17,
          -1+AGGREGATE(
                       15,6,
                       1/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$17,$B$2:$B$17,$C$2:$C$17,"A")*ROW(B2:B17),
                        ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,SUM(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$17,$B$2:$B$17,$C$2:$C$17,"A"))))),
            {1,2})
```

[image]

*Highlighting the `A`'s can be done with simple conditional formatting (eg cell equals `A`)*

Answer (score 1):

To highlight use below formula in conditional formatting.

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2,$E$2:$E$10,0)),$B2="A")
```

[image]

If you want to filter data with `Product` `A` then use below formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$17,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$17)/($B$1:$B$17="A"),ROW(1:1)),COLUMN(A$1)),"")
```

If you have `Office365` then use `Filter()` formula.

```
=FILTER(A1:B17,B1:B17="A")
```